# Updating Sheet Naming Macro Automatically

Tags: excel, autocomplete, vba

I've found a VBA code that allows me to change the sheet name based on a cell value.  That cell values are constantly changing but the 48 sheets that I have do not update unless I click into that sheet.  How do I get the marcos to run every time the cell value changes?

Below is the code that I'm using.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Set Target = Range("DK5")
  If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
  Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using the Worksheet_Change event instead of selection change.  If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("DK5")) Is Nothing Then:  do something: end if

Answer (score 1):

If you always activate the sheet before manually changing the contents of cell **DK5** in that sheet, then enter this event macro in the **each sheet** that you want this functionality:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("DK5")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.Name = Range("DK5").Text
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If cell **DK5** contains a formula, then a different event macro is required.

**EDIT#1:**

If the **DK5** cells contain formulas rather than typed constants, then use these events macro instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Me.Name = Me.Range("Dk5").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*(one macro in each sheet)*

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for the response.  DK5 does include a formula.  What sort of marco would I need then?

Comment: Hey @gary's student.  I wanted to follow up on my question if DK5 is a cell with a formula in it.  What should the code look like then.  The one above didn't work.

Comment: @mfriisje  See my **EDIT#1**